# Reply to comment Using Blogger api in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-api, blogger

I am making an android app using blogger api v3 . But there is no option to reply a comment . Please guide me how can I make option to reply a blogger comment .

Comment: Can you post a comment which is not a reply using the same API?

Comment: I am using blogger v3 for all but I had to use blogger api v2 to post a comment https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#CreatingComments but still I am unable to reply a comment.

Comment: After reading [this](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/reference) you should get an idea how to do it. Hint: There is something related towards the end. Consider editing your post and including a sample code and an answer so that it may help others.